# Remove part of a URL using Apache's Mod_Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to implement a Mod_Rewrite rule so that if users visit the following url:

*www.hostname.uk/home*

They will be served up the real page that exists at:

*www.hostname.uk/uk/home*

i.e. I'm trying to remove the extra /uk/

This is my current rule, however it does not appear to be functioning. Users will receive a "404 page not found" instead.

```
#remove extra uk
RewriteRule ^\.uk/(.*)$ .uk/uk/$1 [NC,L]
```

I am left stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that rule in `.htaccess` or in Virtual Host configuration?

Comment: It's in a .conf included in a Virtual Host config?

Comment: try `RewriteRule !^/uk/ /uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]`

Comment: @Dusan Thank you however due to confusion on my part I was attempting to redirect when actually what I want to do is simply rewrite the displayed url to remove the extra /uk/. This is my current attempt to do so: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/uk/(.*)$ https://www.hostname.uk/$1 [R=301,L]` however again no luck nothing appears to happen.

Comment: Then `RewriteRule ^/uk/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,R]` ?

Comment: @Dusan great this seems to work in the htaccess tester perfectly: `RewriteRule ^uk/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,R]` however has no effect on my setup which would suggest a problem elsewhere. I will keep looking thanks again.